Node inside template tag has isConnected false value


const html = `
  <template id="tmpl">
    <div>a</div>
  </template>
`;
document.body.innerHTML = html;

console.log(tmpl.content.children[0].isConnected);



There is a definition of connected node, I don't see any controversals there is document for tmpl.content.children[0].
Check it via tmpl.content.children[0].ownerDocument.
So why node inside template tag has value .isConnected = false?

The template contents are not children of template element.

The template element can have template contents, but such template contents are not children of the template element itself. Instead, they are stored in a DocumentFragment associated with a different Document — without a browsing context — so as to avoid the template contents interfering with the main Document.

See the specification.

Remarkable note. Yes, it is written there: ...they are stored in a DocumentFragment associated with a different Document — without a browsing context... but it is not controversal of definition connected node. Don't you find that strange?

@MaximPro I don't see what you mean. Are you saying that the shadow-inducing root of the template contents is a document?

yes, or am I mistake and shadow-inducing root of node is document-fragment?
